# How to use the CommandParameter in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am a little lost in how to use the CommandParameter in XAML. I am trying to bind a TextBox and a Button.

**This my XAML code:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCity" Height="70"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Button x:Name="btnCity"
        Content="Get"
        Background="CornflowerBlue"
        Height="70"
        Command="{Binding GetweatherCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtCity, Path=Text}"/>
```

**In my ViewModel class** I have the following to handle the clic action:

```
ActionCommand getWeatherCommand;          //ActionCommand derivides from ICommand
public ActionCommand GetWeatherCommand
{
        get
        {
            if (getClimaCommand != null)
            {
                getClimaCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
                    {
                        serviceModel.getClima("????");
                    });
            }

            return getWeatherCommand;
        }
 }
```

**My ActionCommand class:**

```
public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    Action action;
    public ActionCommand(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

When I debug, the parameters in the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods have the proper value.  However, I guess the problem is in the method from the `ViewClass (GetWeatherCommand)`.  I can't figure out how to pass the parameter.

So, based on the above, does anyone know how can I pass the parameter to the method that will be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionCommand.Execute` is ignoring the command parameter. Try this:

```
public class ActionCommand<TParam> : ICommand
{
    Action<TParam> action;
    public ActionCommand(Action<TParam> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action((TParam)parameter);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
getClimaCommand = new ActionCommand<string>(param =>
    {
        serviceModel.getClima(param);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for your help. I have done some change to my code based in your suggestios. The ActionCommand class has been modified. However, I have a doubt about the last lines of codes. The param at the moment to instantiate the new ActionCommand, is it a variables that you decclared?

Comment: I did the following:

    `ActionCommand<string> getClimaCommand;
    public ActionCommand<string> GetClimaCommand
    {
       get
       {
          if (getClimaCommand != null)
          {
             getClimaCommand = new ActionCommand(param =>
             {
                serviceModel.getClima(param);
             });
          }

       return getClimaCommand;
       }
    }`

Comment: @MikePR - I left out the generic parameter. I've updated it as `<string>` And yes, I assume you'd integrate it back into your property get